# Connect to SFTP server using OpenSSH Private Key

Tags: go, sftp, private-key

I am trying to connect to an SFTP server setup using https://hostedftp.com/. Through the OS X terminal, I can connect to it using the command : `sftp -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss -i <path_to_identity_file_or_private_key> sftp_username@hostname`

When I try to achieve the same above operation using golang packages **crypto/ssh** and **sftp**, I cannot find a suitable example anywhere to connect using a private key. At all places, a relevant example has been given to connect to sftp server using a password.

For reference, I have been trying to use almost the same code as on https://github.com/pkg/sftp/blob/master/examples/buffered-read-benchmark/main.go, but no luck so far. I am unable to figure out on how to add private key to **ssh.ClientConfig** auth method.

Looking for some help with a code sample that connect to sftp server using openssh private key (perhaps its byte array) using golang sftp or crypto/ssh package.

Comment: The [`ClientConfig`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh#ClientConfig) (used by an SSH client instance) has the `Auth` field, which might contain 1 or more instances types representing different authentication methods. One of them is "pubkey" (which is what you need), and preparing an appropriate instance for it is covered by [this example](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh#AuthMethod).

Comment: Thank you Kostix for your answer. That example link actually helped (referring to the example stated under func PublicKeys at the link you shared) and I was able to successfully connect to sftp server using keys with a little glitch. But it worked finally !  :)